# Specified JDBC Driver: org.h2.jdbc - initialization failed

Tags: jdbc, h2

Can't connect to database.

I also added the latest `h2-1.4.178.jar` to classpath, create table, check connection through tools.

It's working, but Tomcat said: "HTTP Status 500 - com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Specified JDBC Driver: org.h2.jdbc - initialization failed."

How can I call it? I use Eclipse. This is my src (I use Vaadin):

```
try {
        JDBCConnectionPool pool = new SimpleJDBCConnectionPool(
                "org.h2.jdbc",
                "jdbc:h2:~test", "SA", "", 2, 5);
        screen.polulate("TEST", pool);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

I found my problem (https://superuser.com/questions/290999/where-can-i-find-h2-jdbc-driver), but i cant understand what does it mean:

> And then call
>
> ```
> Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you link to is not really relevant to your problem. The problem **probably** (educated guess) is that the first parameter of the constructor of `SimpleJDBCConnectionPool` expects the JDBC driver name, and `"org.h2.jdbc"` is not the JDBC driver name (it's `"org.h2.Driver"`).

Using `Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");` is no longer necessary for modern JDBC drivers. With old drivers (that don't include a file `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` with its driver implementation(s)) using `Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");` will load the driver and then the driver will register itself with `java.sql.DriverManager` so it can be used to create connections.

Comment: thanks Mark, Problem was that i didnt copy *.jars in WEB-INF/lib